# An issue with memory allocations of arrays of the same size

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

I'm having a weird behaviour with my C++ code. Here it is.

```
OI_Id * Reqlist = 0;
int * Idlist = 0;
int Reqsize = listcount;  // we calculate listcount somehow earlier.

Idlist = new int [Reqsize];
if (Idlist == 0)
{
    return;
}
printf ("Idlist = %0x",Idlist);

Reqlist = new OI_Id [Reqsize]; // OI_Id is a 3rd party lib simple struct.
if (Reqlist == 0)
{
    return;
}
printf ("Reqlist = %0x",Reqlist);
```

So the problem is that in both cases it prints the same value - the same pointer is returned by the new operator. BUT! If we change the length of second allocated array to another value (`Reqsize+ 1`, for example), everything is OK.

Did anybody meet any similar behaviour? I have no idea what's the reason of the problem.

Comment: Try printing pointers with `%p`.

Comment: What OS and processor?

Comment: I think, that problem is somewhere else, because this code - http://ideone.com/MR9AT2 - gives different prints

Comment: @juanchopanza the problem is not in the output. Furhter work with these pointers leads to errors with data - the data in the first array is overwritten when working with the second one

Comment: Then your code is broken, somewhere that you are not showing. In any case, replace the calls to `printf` with `std::cout`. That will avoid one potential source of undefined behaviour.